# Making GTK applications look decent under KDE

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, kde, gtk

I just installed the latest Ubuntu (Karmic Koala) and thought that I could try out using KDE as my desktop for a change. I got it mostly set up to my liking, but there are certain applications which are from the gnome-side (gtk-based) which look ugly (e.g. synaptic). They use some default look and feel for their buttons and other widgets. How can I change their themes under KDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install qtcurve (sudo apt-get install qtcurve).
install gtk-chtheme.
then choose qtcurve in **system settings >> appearance >> style** 
(windows decoration can also use qtcurve)
run gtk-chtheme and choose qtcurve as well.

now your window themes are unified.

--

hint: in **system settings >> appearance >> style** there is a configure option.
it allows you to configure lots of things. you can also use predefined styles, just check the 'options' in the down-left corner of qtcurve configuration.
it wil apply to both qt and gtk :)

Comment: Also, if you're changing font settings, make sure that you change it for both KDE and GTK.